# RODBC connection issues

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc

Something is wrong in my connection string and I cannot seem to figure it out.

Here is my code —

```
datalithicdb <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server};localhost/sqlexpress;database=datalithic;trusted_connection=TRUE;")
```

— and the error messages I receive —

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server};localhost/sqlexpress;
   database=datalithic;trusted_connection=yes;"):
      [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL 
      Server Driver]Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied 
2: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server};localhost/sqlexpress;
   database=datalithic;trusted_connection=yes;"): 
      [RODBC] ERROR: state 01S00, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL 
      Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute 
3: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server};localhost/sqlexpress;
   database=datalithic;trusted_connection=yes;"):
      ODBC connection failed
```

Windows authentication works fine when I open the database straight out of SQL Management Studio.

New to web development so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Change from `trusted_connection=yes` to `trusted_connection=TRUE`

Comment: Changed that and am still getting the same errors

Comment: Still no answer, come on R community...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing **server=** and you also need a double forward slash between your computer name and SQLEXPRESS. Instead of just *;localhost/sqlexpress* it should say

```
;server=yourCOMPUTERname\\SQLEXPRESS
```

So if your database is called *datalithic*, and your computer was called  *workstation123*, and you are using Microsoft SQL Express, and your SQL server uses your Windows authentication to connect, then your R connection would read like this:

```
datalithicdb<-odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server};server=workstation123\\SQLEXPRESS;database=datalithic;trusted_connection=TRUE;")
```